# How to split a variable using explode function in php

Tags: php, explode

I am trying to split string like below

```
<?php    
$str = "Q:1) What is PHP?Opensource,cms,framework,webservice,opensource
        Q:2) What is Laravel?Opensource,cms,framework,webservice,framework     
        Q:3) What is Wordpress?Opensource,cms,framework,webservice,framwork     
        Q:4) What is Shopify?Opensource,cms,framework,webservice,framwork       
        Q:5) What is Mangento?Opensource,cms,framework,webservice,framwork";    

$ex = explode("Q:",$str);    
echo $ex[0];
```

It displays nothing

Answer (score 4):

The 0th index will be empty since th `Q:` is at the starting location. So start with index 1 onwards

Your result would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 1) What is PHP?Opensource,cms,framework,webservice,opensource 
    [2] => 2) What is Laravel?Opensource,cms,framework,webservice,framework 
    [3] => 3) What is Wordpress?Opensource,cms,framework,webservice,framwork 
    [4] => 4) What is Shopify?Opensource,cms,framework,webservice,framwork 
    [5] => 5) What is Mangento?Opensource,cms,framework,webservice,framwork
)
```

---

**Possible workaround:**

You can over come this by applying [`array_shift`](http://php.net/array_shift):

```
array_shift($ex);
```

This will shift an element off the beginning of your exploded array. Then your array will become:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1) What is PHP?Opensource,cms,framework,webservice,opensource 
    [1] => 2) What is Laravel?Opensource,cms,framework,webservice,framework 
    [2] => 3) What is Wordpress?Opensource,cms,framework,webservice,framwork 
    [3] => 4) What is Shopify?Opensource,cms,framework,webservice,framwork 
    [4] => 5) What is Mangento?Opensource,cms,framework,webservice,framwork
)
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because the first occurrence of "Q:" is at the very beginning of the string, so the first item in $ex is an empty string. try outputting the second item instead `$echo $ex[1];`, it should give you

`"1) What is PHP?Opensource,cms,framework,webservice,opensource"`

Comment: i got it, thanx

Comment: although Im glad i could help i want you to accept Thamilans answer since it is the same answer but way more detailed. ;) cheers